# Allow visitor to print something they bought only 1 time

Tags: php, print

I am doing a website that needs to only let the customer print out what they bought 1 time. There are websites that currently do this and they mentioned  Adobe Flash Player, Adobe AIR and the Sheet Music Plus AIR application.

We would need to block programs like adobe distillation and any virtual printers while only allowing an instant print after purchase.

I am not an adobe air developer. Would their be any other ways to accomplish this and what would be the easiest. Thank you.

Would their be a way to not allow printing to a virtual printer ie adobe pdf?

Comment: Just my two cents: are you sure this will be the best solution? Once I printed something I can Xerox copy it w/o any problem. But restricting the amount of prints will just give you support headaches every time a printer jams or something goes wrong. I would never buy something that I am not 100% sure it will be in my hands.

Comment: That is a good point however I am delivering this product for a client and they have made it clear that this is a have to have aspect.

Comment: ctrl + print scrn and the business model falls over...

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to have a low resolution or watermarked version of the product visible on the web site and the full resolution/non-watermarked version behind a link that is a database call.

You can then store the fact that the user has printed the page and not allow them access to the page again. There is the issue of only letting them select print once while on the page, but if the "Print" button is coupled with a navigation away from the page then that should solve that problem.